# Lightning Community Custom Theme/Component/Content Language change (text/button label)

Tags: lightning, community, translation, translation-workbench

Any one has idea on how to change language based on profile language for text and button labels for a custom component in lightning communities? I tried to add language to the community page but it is only translating the standard components and only the component label is changing not the content. Attached is a screenshot of a standard object where only the label is translating into different language and not the content.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [Custom Labels](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_about.htm&type=5) for that.

After creating custom label, you can use in cmp by using [{!$Label.c.labelName}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm) OR you can use [$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm) in Javascript of component.

Then you should translate the labels in translation workbench or [Directly](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_translate_edit.htm&type=5)

After these steps you should see the labels in chosen language.